# Programmatically change Facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

Two questions:

- Is there any way to programmatically create a facebook fan page?
- Is there any way to programmatically add a content tab to an existing Facebook fan page and edit it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all original creation should be done by a user.  There are captcha forms in use to prevent automated generation.